# How JSONObject method getBoolean("error") works?

Tags: java, android, json

I have following code which includes error checking expression:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
if (!obj.getBoolean("error"))
```

I am wondering, how **getBoolean(String name)** works, will it search just "error" string in whole response body & return TRUE or FALSE as we did not provide any arguments except "error" or there is something deeper than this?
Is "error" a **key** or a **value** in the returned object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"error"` is a key.

`JSONObject` represents a single object in JSON, and the `JSONObject.getBoolean(String key)` method looks for a key-value pair with the given key in that object. It look only at the first level of that one object, not deeper.

Answer (score 0):

`error` in `obj.getBoolean("error")` is the key name. `getBoolean` method looks for `error` key name and returns its value if it exists and is of Boolean type else throws `JSONException`. Use `optBoolean` instead which returns `false` for exception or fallback value if specified.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
'''boolean remarks = processInput.containsKey("status"); '''